# CSS Bug with IE, Firefox & Edge

Tags: html, css

I am at a complete loss as to what is wrong here.  I've been at it for quite some time but no luck.  For some reason whenever I load my page in IE or Firefox I get scrollable bars on some of my divs and the font sizes seem to be larger.  I have an odd feeling that whatever the root cause is, it is causing both problems.

Here is where you can see the page: https://jsfiddle.net/041j4e9b/

Just load it in chrome and you will see it looks fine, even Opera and Safari windows load it fine.  But then load it in IE, Edge or Firefox and you will what I am talking about.  Below username and password you will see scrollable bars. Remember me and forgot password fonts are also much bigger in IE & Edge than in chrome, they can't fit on the single line.  Firefox doesn't seem to have the font-size problem.

I have done my best to isolate the relevant code.  The below html and css is required to load and show you everything that you see, I understand that this is a bit more code than required, but I honestly cannot remove more without altering the outcome and having a different issue than what I have on my original website.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="login-page-wrapper">
            <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="login-dialog-wrapper">
                        <div class="single-element-wrapper">
                            <input value="" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-element-wrapper">
                            <input value="" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-element-wrapper adjusted-height">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button-login">
                            <a class="button-link button-register">Register</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-element-wrapper">
                            <div class="remember-me">
                                <input data-val="true" type="checkbox" value="true">
                                <label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="forgot-password">
                                <a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

body{
  background: #000;
}
input[type=text] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: condensed;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill, input[type=text]:-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px green inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
}
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder, input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder, input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder, input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}

input[type=password] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: condensed;
}
input[type=password]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=password]:-webkit-autofill, input[type=password]:-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px green inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
}
input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder, input[type=password]:-moz-placeholder, input[type=password]::-moz-placeholder, input[type=password]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}

input[type=submit], button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
}
input[type=submit]:focus, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=submit]::-webkit-input-placeholder, button::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:-moz-placeholder, button:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]::-moz-placeholder, button::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:-ms-input-placeholder, button:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:hover, button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FF6A00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #ff6a00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.button-link {
  display: block;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a.button-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FF6A00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueLightCondensed", "HelveticaNeue-Light-Condensed", "Helvetica Neue Light Condensed", "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "TeXGyreHerosCnRegular", "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Arial Narrow", "Arial", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  color: #FFF;
}
html body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html body .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("../../Images/Shared/30-Percent-Black-Background.png");
  height: 100%;
}

.login-page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .button-login {
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .button-register {
  float: right;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .remember-me {
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .forgot-password {
  float: right;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .adjusted-height {
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This is caused by `overflow: auto`. what if you make it `visible` instead?

Comment: fixed with `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @freestock.tk on which element?  Does this also fixes the font size issue?

Comment: @Aziz I can try but I feel we are hacking the css at this point.  as the width will still be there pushing the other elements by 2 pixels.  Yes I know its now much, but if there is a way to fix that width properly I'd go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did use `box-sizing: border-box` on the input elements, plus removed `overflow: auto` from the buttons' wrapper (as [@Aziz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877671/aziz) have commented) :

Screenshot of the result at Chrome 49/Firefox 45:

[image: screenshot]

Code:

```css
* {  
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueLightCondensed", "HelveticaNeue-Light-Condensed", "Helvetica Neue Light Condensed", "HelveticaNeueLight", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "TeXGyreHerosCnRegular", "Helvetica", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Arial Narrow", "Arial", "sans-serif";
}

input[type=text] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=text]:-webkit-autofill, input[type=text]:-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px green inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
}
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder, input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder, input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder, input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
input[type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=text]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}

input[type=password] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=password]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=password]:-webkit-autofill, input[type=password]:-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px green inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: red !important;
}
input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder, input[type=password]:-moz-placeholder, input[type=password]::-moz-placeholder, input[type=password]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: green;
}
input[type=password]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=password]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}

input[type=submit], button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  height: 60px;
  color: #FF6A00;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit]:focus, button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=submit]::-webkit-input-placeholder, button::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:-moz-placeholder, button:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]::-moz-placeholder, button::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:-ms-input-placeholder, button:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #FF6A00;
}
input[type=submit]:hover, button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FF6A00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  color: #ff6a00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.button-link {
  display: block;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 150px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a.button-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FF6A00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 320px;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #FFF;
}
html body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: black;
}
html body .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url("../../Images/Shared/30-Percent-Black-Background.png");
  height: 100%;
}

.login-page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .button-login {
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .button-register {
  float: right;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .remember-me {
  float: left;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper .forgot-password {
  float: right;
}
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .adjusted-height {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="login-page-wrapper">
<div class="login-wrapper">
<div class="login-dialog-wrapper">
<div class="single-element-wrapper">
<input value="" placeholder="Username" type="text">
</div>
<div class="single-element-wrapper">
<input value="" placeholder="Password" type="password">
</div>
<div class="single-element-wrapper adjusted-height">
<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="button-login">
<a class="button-link button-register">Register</a>
</div>
<div class="single-element-wrapper">
<div class="remember-me">
<input data-val="true" type="checkbox" value="true">
<label for="RememberMe">Remember me?</label>
</div>
<div class="forgot-password">
<a href="">Forgot Password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/041j4e9b/4/)

Comment: Yeah that does fixes the scrolling, but do you have any idea about the font size?

Comment: Sorry but I don't see any difference at the font **size**: the difference I can notice is at the font **color** and also at the font **family** (the font family difference gets easier to notice at the letters 'I' and 'g' from the 'Log In' button on my screenshots. It wasn't my focus when answering the question so I'll check it later (my focus was to remove the scrollbars - which seems to be the main problem).

Comment: the font sizes are correct, 21.  But if you notice for some reason on chrome the two texts fit on a single line, but in IE they do not, they are too large.

Comment: You are using the `font-strech` css3 property which isnt supported by any browser at the moment; sounds like a good idea remove it from your entire code (it happens more than once).

Comment: updated with font-family issue fixed; The difference of the orange color between the screenshots seems to be the standard placeholder opacity of each browser, so isnt really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **overflow: auto;** form the below css code.

```
.login-page-wrapper .login-wrapper .login-dialog-wrapper .single-element-wrapper {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```